# How to remove admin footer text from inside child theme?

Tags: functions, child-theme

I am using this set of functions in child theme to remove unneeded footer info:

```
add_filter( 'admin_footer_text', '__return_empty_string', 11 ); 
add_filter( 'update_footer', '__return_empty_string', 11 );
```

It all worked well while in theme sixteen. Now, in child theme, those filters are not working.

How to solve this issue, as this is not only filter I am using.

Comment: This kind of backend modification sounds better served in a plugin than depending on the theme.

Comment: I do have that backend UI theme modification. I am going to try it. Thanks.

Comment: @birgire, it is working. How to grant correct answer to you? One more thing, just because of this, I do not need child theme. And that is great for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, these kind of modifications would be better served with a custom plugin, as they are not theme dependent. Here's an example:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Remove Footer Text
 * Description: Remove admin footer text and update footer text through filters.
 * Version:     0.0.1
 * Author:      Name
 * Author URI:  http://example.tld
 */

add_filter( 'admin_footer_text', '__return_empty_string', 11 ); 
add_filter( 'update_footer',     '__return_empty_string', 11 );
```

*Setup*: Create the `/wp-content/plugins/wpse-remove-footer-text/plugin.php` and activate the plugin from the backend as usual.

If other plugins or the themes are adjusting the footer text, then we might need to increase the *priority* value.